# Having issues with passing vars to html files using flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to make a card game in python for the web and i need to generate random cards, when i do this i run a function that makes the file name of the card.

```
def create_card_name():
    random = get_random_line("random.txt")
    alsorandom = get_random_line("alsorandom.txt")
    ## return alsorandom + random + ".svg"
    print(alsorandom +"_"+ random)
```

Then i create it when the site is opened i get the values set to vars:

```
    card1 = create_card_name()
    card2 = create_card_name()
    card3 = create_card_name()
    card4 = create_card_name()
```

When i pass it in with:
`return render_template('card-game.html',card1=card1,card2=card2,card3=card3,card4=card4)`

I get none for some reason. [See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1fdc.png)

Anyone know why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside `create_card_name` function, you should return a value. and return statement must be last line. your last line is print`(..)` which returns `None` thus your `create_card_name()` evaluates to `None`

```
def create_card_name():
    random = get_random_line("random.txt")
    alsorandom = get_random_line("alsorandom.txt")
    print(alsorandom +"_"+ random)
    return alsorandom + random + ".svg"
```